# WPF consuming WCF

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm

I am hosting a WCF service on a server, and I want to consume the service from my WPF application. My WPF application is written in the MVVM design pattern in two assemblies, one containing the view (xaml), and another containing the models and viewmodels. This works great on its own, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the view model consume the service. I tried making both the view assembly and the model/viewmodel assembly reference the service, but that didn't work. The code fails when I try to create a new instance of the client proxy class:

```
WCFServiceClient = new WCFServiceClient(new InstanceContext(this));
```

in the viewmodel. The exception thrown says:

> Could not find default endpoint that references contract 'WCFService.IWCFService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I know my WCF works because I have other client applications in winforms that are accessing it properly. Any idea on how this should be done?

Comment: Did you use the add service reference? That generates the proxy clases and also adds all the configuration to the app.config Also which version of visual studio and .net framework are you using

Comment: Yes I did. The WCF works perfectly with my winforms applications. I'm just trying to port it over to WPF.

Comment: It should be done the exact same way as in the winforms app.  WPF has nothing to do with this issue.  I'd wager you're configuring the service in the DLL's app.config file (the assembly with your view models) rather than in your executable's app.config.  It needs to go into the project which drops the .exe.

Comment: That's bloody brilliant! Thanks!